# 'a' does not contain a definition for 'b' and no extenstion method error

Tags: c#

So, I'm getting a bunch of different errors and being new to C#, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am creating a new method "method A" inside my ImportDefinitionData class like shown below. It does not like the way I've defined the Area-description variable. I get a "classa.field A" cannot declare instance members in a static class error.

Then, when I try to call that method from another class, I get a red squiggly line under the method name and the error states "Definitiondata does not contain a definition for Phase1Additionalparameters and no extension method accepting a first argument of type Definition data could be found.

Comment: You put it in ImportDefinitionData, not DefinitionData...

Comment: your class is `ImportDefinitionData`, but you're trying to use some class `DefinitionData`.  Also `this` isn't valid inside a static method.

Comment: You can´t have a public variable inside a member (such as a method). Move the `public string AREA_DESCRIPTION;`-part into the class-body, not inside the method.

Comment: The answers given should correct your error. Now would be a good time to correct your style as well. C# developers do not use SHOUTING_SNAKE_CASE.  Use `areaDescription` for a field or `AreaDescription` for a property.

Comment: Also, fields should be `private`. If you want a public field, instead say `public string AreaDescription { get; set; }` to make a public property. Note that you can also make a read-only property (only settable in the constructor) with `{get;}` or a property that can only be set in your class with `{get; private set;}`. Best practice is to lock down set-ability as much as possible.

Comment: Also, use embedded expressions in strings instead of calling `Format` explicitly.  `$"{this.AreaName} {this.AreaName}";`

Comment: Also, consider *computing* computable read-only properties rather than *setting* them.  So let's put it all together. This probably should be `public string AreaDescription => $"{this.AreaName} {this.areaName}";`  Notice how concise this is, with very little loss of readability.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is a bunch of errors.

First you can´t use `this` in a static member (in your case a static method). Furthermore you can´t define an member (static or not) within another one, this is you can´t use `public` *within* a method.

So to shortcome this use the following:

```
public static class ImportDefinitionData
{
    public string AREA_DESCRIPTION;

    public static DefinitionData Import(string DefinitionFile)
    {
        DefinitionData definitionData = XMLDefinitionFile.Read(DefinitionFile);
        return definitionData;
    }

    public static void Phase1AdditionalParameters()
    {

        AREA_DESCRIPTION = string.Format("{0} {1}", AREA_NAME, AREA_TYPE);
    }
}
```

However I´m not quite sure where `AREA_NAME` and `AREA_TYPE` come from, so you might expect further errors here.

Anyway you should definitly have a look at access-modifiers and principles of OOP, in particular what an instance of a class means and how to use the `this`-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the line below

```
this.AREA_DESCRIPTION = string.Format(...
```

Which should just be below since it's a local parameter

```
AREA_DESCRIPTION = string.Format(...
```